# How can I count occurrences of different types from my table using a raw query?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, database

I have a table named `partner`. In the `partner` table I have one column named `type` where I store the type of partner: either yearly, monthly, or weekly.

I want to count the types of partner. For example, here I count the user account yearly. Similarly, I want to count the types of partner.

```
  $year = ['2015','2016','2017','2018','2019','2020','2021','2022'];
    $user = [];
    $type = ['Yearly','Monthly','Weekly'];
    $partner = [];
    foreach ($year as $key => $value) {
        $user[] = User::where(\DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y')"),$value)->count();
    }
```

Comment: So where exactly are you stuck? You should also post the code you have issues with. Posting some other code that isn't or isn't suppose to give you the same result is pointless. Post your actual attempt incl. database schema, example data, expected output and what you currently get.

Comment: Simply I want to count this  $type = ['Yearly','Monthly','Weekly']; occurrence How many partner are yearly. weekly,monthly etc. like this $user[] = User::where(\DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y')"),$value)->count(); but I stuck here  Partner::where(\DB::raw("???????')"),$type )

Comment: OR simply tell me please how can I use this query 
 $user[] = User::where(\DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y')"),$value)->count();
for me name column if I want to Count how many time name (A/B/C) occur

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/32149143) your question to include any missing information and code. Code chunks in comments are unreadable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about the structure of Partner table . If the column type is varchar and you actual store 'Yearly' or 'Monthly' or 'Weekly'  then you do not need `DB::raw` , just

```
foreach ($type as $key => $value) {
            $partner[] = Partner::where('type',$value)->count();               
        }
```

If you want the query to be raw then you can try this (of course, I do not recommend writing code like this, is is just an example)

```
foreach ($type as $key => $value) {
    $query = DB::select(DB::raw("select count(type) as count from partner where type like  '" . $value . "'"));
    if ($query) {
        $partner[] = $query[0]->count;
    }
}
```

You can use `DB::enableQueryLog();` before the execution of the query and  `dd( DB::getQueryLog());` to see what query is executed.